# XSLT Transform from a Generic Model to a Specific Model

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to convert a XML form that is sent to my backend using a generic model to the internal XML model the system uses using XSLT.

The generic model consists of sections, lines and tables (a table is basically an array/group of elements). The PK's are from the sequence for the tableRow and the maxPK is a count. MaxPK I can probably populate afterwards, not sure if that is possible through XSLT.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Generic Model**

```
    <form>
    <section>
        <name>identification</name>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <line>
            <sequence>0</sequence>
            <field>
                <name>firstName</name>
                <value>JOHN</value>
            </field>
        </line>
        <line>
            <sequence>1</sequence>
            <field>
                <name>lastName</name>
                <value>DOE</value>
            </field>
        </line>
    </section>
    <section>
        <name>contactDetails</name>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <line>
            <sequence>0</sequence>
            <field>
                <name>primaryPhone</name>
                <value>+44 100 1234</value>
            </field>
        </line>
        <table>
            <name>secondaryPhoneGroup</name>
            <tableRow>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <field>
                    <sequence>0</sequence>
                    <name>secondaryPhone</name>
                    <value>+44 100 1235</value>
                </field>
            </tableRow>
            <tableRow>
                <sequence>2</sequence>
                <field>
                    <sequence>0</sequence>
                    <name>secondaryPhone</name>
                    <value>+44 100 1236</value>
                </field>
            </tableRow>
        </table>
    </section>
</form>
```

**Internal Model**

```
<form>
    <identification>
        <firstName>
            <asCurrent>JOHN</asCurrent>
        </firstName>
        <lastName>
            <asCurrent>DOE</asCurrent>
        </lastName>
    </identification>
    <contactDetails>
        <primaryPhone>
            <asCurrent>+44 100 1234</asCurrent>
        </primaryPhone>
        <secondaryPhoneGroup>
            <secondaryPhone>
                <pk>1</pk>
                <phone>
                    <asCurrent>+44 100 1235</asCurrent>
                </phone>
            </secondaryPhone>
            <secondaryPhone>
                <pk>2</pk>
                <phone>
                    <asCurrent>+44 100 1236</asCurrent>
                </phone>
            </secondaryPhone>
            <maxPK>2</maxPK>
        </secondaryPhoneGroup>
    </contactDetails>
</form>
```

Comment: So what are the rules, what have you tried? Where does the data for e.g. `pk` and `maxPK` from, is that just the position respectively the element count?

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to avoid confusion and to help future visitors. You can find the removed solution in your [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44864560/revisions). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try along the following lines:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="line">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sequence"/>

    <xsl:template match="section | field">
        <xsl:element name="{name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* except name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[name]/value">
        <asCurrent>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </asCurrent>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:element name="{name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* except name"/>
            <maxPK>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(tableRow)"/>
            </maxPK>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tableRow">
        <xsl:element name="{field/name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* except name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tableRow/sequence">
        <pk>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </pk>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tableRow/field[name = 'secondaryPhone']">
        <phone>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="value"/>
        </phone>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! 

I made a mistake in my original spec which made it more confusing, but with your help, I was able to crack it! The * except name notation did not work for me, but replacing it with *[not(self::name)] did the trick.

Comment: `except` is part of XSLT/XPath 2.0 and later, as you tagged your question with that version I considered it safe to be used. But you have found an alternative expression for XSLT 1.0.